# Binding with cconverter fails

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to set up some binding. And FYI I'm using the MVVM pattern.

### I have this control in my xaml code

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <src:ActivityViewToToolTipContentConverter x:Key="tooltipConverter"></src:ActivityViewToToolTipContentConverter>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomNonWorkingBrush" Color="#DFE9F2" Opacity="0.75"/>
</Grid.Resources>

<gantt:GanttControl Name="GanttChart"
                    IDBinding="{Binding TaskID}"
                    NameBinding="{Binding TaskName}"
                    IndentLevelBinding="{Binding IndentLevel}"
                    StartTimeBinding="{Binding StartDate}"
                    PredecessorIndicesBinding="{Binding PredecessorIndices}"
                    DescriptionBinding="{Binding TaskResponsible}"
                    SortOrderBinding="{Binding SortOrder}"
                    ToolTipContentBinding="{Binding ActualTaskResponsibleDepartment, Converter={StaticResource tooltipConverter}}" //It is this line I am talking about
                    TemplateApplied="GanttChart_TemplateApplied"
                    CanUserReorderRows="True"
                    NonWorkingTimeBackground="{StaticResource CustomNonWorkingBrush}"
                    SyncRowBackgrounds="True"
                    AdjustDurationOnAssignment="False"
                    DependencyLineAdded="GanttChart_DependencyLineChanged"
                    DependencyLineRemoved="GanttChart_DependencyLineChanged"

                    Loaded="GanttChart_Loaded"
                    />
```

I have my converter in a different file called "ActivityViewToToolTipContentConverter.cs"

When I run the code I get this exception:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'ActualTaskResponsibleDepartment' property not found on 'object'
>   ''GanttActivityView' (Name='')'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=ActualTaskResponsibleDepartment;
>   DataItem='GanttActivityView' (Name=''); target element is 'ToolTip'
>   (Name='TaskTooltip'); target property is 'Content' (type 'Object')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has your DataContext (bound to GanttActivityView) a property ActualTaskResponsibleDepartment?

Comment: Now I found the problem but not a solution. The problem is as you also told that GanttActivityView doesn't contain the vaiable. Now the problem is that GanttActivityView is autogenerated within the Gantt Component so I don't see how to add the variable to it?!

Comment: So simply, when the autogenerated view hasn't got that property you can't bind to it... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

When bindings fail that never has anything to do with the converter and as the error *clearly* states you try to bind to a property that is not found on the view that is the DataContext.